# API Integration for ProductSync in volusion

Tags: php, xml, api, http, volusion

Here is the method provide by Volusion support for ProductSync but the code in C# i want to implement in PHP but how to implement it i don't know.

https://support.volusion.com/hc/en-us/articles/209637767-API-Integration-ProductSync-Developer-

So anyone can help me that how to implement in PHP because i am working on PHP i have no knowledge of C#. I just copy this code in paste in my PHP it give me an error like this

> Fatal error: Class 'XMLHTTP' not found in /home/tlztech/public_html/volusion/productSync.php on line 5.

And my code as under.

```html
<?php

$api_url = "http://tebkq.mvlce.servertrust.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mylogin&EncryptedPassword=mypass&API_Name=Generic\\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.StockStatus";

$xml_http = new XMLHTTP();
$xml_http.open("POST", $api_url, false, "", "");
$xml_http.send(null);
$api_response = $xml_http.responseText;



$api_url = "http://tebkq.mvlce.servertrust.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mylogin&EncryptedPassword=mypass&Import=Update";
$api_request = "";
$api_request = $api_request + "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
$api_request = $api_request + "<xmldata>";
$api_request = $api_request + "   <Products>";
$api_request = $api_request + "       <ProductCode>0001</ProductCode>";
$api_request = $api_request + "       <StockStatus>5</StockStatus>";
$api_request = $api_request + "   </Products>";
$api_request = $api_request + "</xmldata>";

$xml_http = new XMLHTTP();
$xml_http.open("POST", $api_url, false, "", "");
$xml_http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
$xml_http.setRequestHeader("Content-Action", "Volusion_API");
$xml_http.send(api_request);
$xml_http = $xml_http.responseText;

$api_url = "http://tebkq.mvlce.servertrust.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mylogin&EncryptedPassword=mypass&API_Name=Generic\\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.StockStatus&WHERE_Column=p.ProductCode&WHERE_Value=0002";

$xml_http = new XMLHTTP();
$xml_http.open("POST", $api_url, false, "", "");
$xml_http.send(null);
$api_response = $xml_http.responseText;


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference a Microsoft class that doesn't exist in PHP.

I see in your other recent threads that you've tried to call the Volusion API with cURL.  This is a valid approach that I use with PHP.  There's no need to adapt the C# example into PHP.

Here is a valid example in PHP using cURL and your URL example:

```
$api_url = "http://tebkq.mvlce.servertrust.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mylogin&EncryptedPassword=mypass&Import=Update";

$api_request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$api_request .= '<xmldata>';
$api_request .= '   <Products>';
$api_request .= '       <ProductCode>0001</ProductCode>';
$api_request .= '       <StockStatus>5</StockStatus>';
$api_request .= '   </Products>';
$api_request .= '</xmldata>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_request); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", "Content-Action:Volusion_API"));

$head = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I tried all the methods for insertion of products in Volusion but I until can't  success. I posts many question about this issue no one can give the correct answer.

Comment: can you give me any reference that you use cURL or any peice of code.??

Comment: Sure -- see above

Comment: Now when I echo my http-code **$http_code**  I am getting **403**.code and  header **$head** returns nothing. Also the product is not yet updated.

Comment: Can you post your XML here?  Are you trying to update an existing product?  If you are trying to insert a new product, are you sure that it's not in the system already?

Comment: i just try this sample XML in above code. Which save in $api_request variable

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to use namespace of you're XMLHTTP class :

`$xml_http = new Your\Namespace\XMLHTTP();`

because there is no XMLHTTP class in your file. That's why it is not found

Then if you want to use only `XMLHTTP()` you need to add a use at the beginning of your file:

`use <NAMESPACE>;`

If this class is from the global namespace just do it like that :
`$xml_http = new \XMLHTTP();`

Comment: when i try this i get this error

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/tlztech/public_html/volusion/productSync.php on line 2".

What is meant by this??

Comment: When I said `<NAMESPACE>` it is not exactly `<NAMESPACE>` you need to write but a real namespace like `use Your\Namespace\XMLHTTP;`